# Experience with JDK 1.6.x G1 ("Garbage First")

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, garbage-collection, java-6, g1gc

I'd like to know what are the experiences with G1 garbage collector in newest JDK?  I see `NullPointerException` thrown in my program, although code didn't change and behave correctly in earlier JDKs.

Comment: Remember that it is an experimental feature so problems are to be expected.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?  There's a chance that you've exposed a timing / concurrency problem with the new collector.

Comment: I received random OutOfMemoryError exceptions mostly on array allocations. With normal GC, no problems occurrs.

Comment: I would try -XX:MaxPermSize=512m option, or some other things, before resorting to the new garbage collector.

Comment: I tried to run Netbeans with G1. Several errors kept occuring from time to time. So switched back to normal GC.

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111310/java-7-jdk-7-garbage-collection-and-documentation/34254605#34254605

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been running jEdit using:

```
-Xmx192M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC
```

for the last couple of days on windows. Haven't experienced anything going wrong or misbehaving.

I also tried running Intellij using the G1 GC, it didn't fair so well. It lasted a couple of hours before crashing in a big pile of mess, a bit optimistic maybe.

Answer (score 3):

A garbage collector will only impact the *performance* of your application, not its *correctness*. I've been using it for Eclipse, just for fun, and seemed stable.

I would look elsewhere for the source of the exceptions.

Comment: A bug in garbage collector, on the other hand, *can* impact its correctness. Something about "experimental" tells me it's not completely unreasonable to question the situation. :)

Comment: I agree that it is experimental and I would not use it production, at least not with u14.

Answer (score 1):

I tried and experienced no exceptions. But performance of our server dropped about 30%.

Comment: That's disappointing that you saw such a significant performance degradation, but it's important to remember that an important goal of the G1 collector is to minimize pauses.  With a heap of a few GB or higher, you can get multiple minute pauses when GC runs with the other collectors.  So, even if G1 leads to somewhat longer response times, as long as they are more consistent and never exhibit the worst-case behavior, that would be a great improvement for some apps.

Comment: you should post all your VM options for us here so that we can compare with your "30% drop analysis".