# Tuning JVM (GC) for high responsive server application

Tags: java, performance, jvm, garbage-collection

I am running an application server on Linux 64bit with 8 core CPUs and 6 GB memory.

The server must be highly responsive.

After some inspection I found that the application running on the server creates rather a huge amount of short-lived objects, and has only about 200~400 MB long-lived objects(as long as there is no memory leak)

After reading http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/gc_tuning_6.html
I use these JVM options

```
-server -Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:NewRatio=1 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Result: the minor GC takes 0.01 ~ 0.02 sec, the major GC takes 1 ~ 3 sec
the minor GC happens constantly.

How can I further improve or tune the JVM?

larger heap size? but will it take more time for GC?

larger NewSize and MaxNewSize (for young generation)?

other collector? parallel GC?

is it a good idea to let major GC take place more often? and how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Result: the minor GC takes 0.01 ~ 0.02 sec, the major GC takes 1 ~ 3 sec the minor GC happens constantly.

Unless you are reporting pauses, I would say that the CMS collector is doing what you have asked it to do.  By definition, CMS will use a larger percentage of the CPU than the Serial and Parallel collectors.  This is the penalty you pay for low pause times.

If you are seeing 1 to 3 second *pause* times, I'd say that you need to do some tuning.  I'm no expert, but it looks like you should start by reducing the value of `CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction` from the default value of 92.

Increasing the heap size will improve the "throughput" of the GC.  But if your problem is long pauses, increasing the heap size is likely to make the problem worse.

Comment: `CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction` default value is -1 and cms use `CMSTriggerRatio` which default value is  80 .

Comment: @shaoyihe - Please provide references so that I can update the Answer,

Comment: I see the answer time . It is 2010's answer , maybe something has changed .

Comment: Yea ... those were my thoughts too.  But I can't research this until later.

Answer (score 3):

Careful .... GC can be a hairy subject if you are not cautious.  Within any runtime (JVM for Java / CLR for .Net) there are several processes that take place.  Generally there is an early stage optimization of memory (Young Generational Garbage Collection / Young Gen GC & Old Generational Garbage Collection / Old Gen GC).  The young gen gc happens on a regular basis and is commonly attributed to your smaller pauses / hiccups.  The old gen gc is normally what is going on when you see the long "stop the world" pauses.

Why you might ask?  The reason you get pauses with your runtime / JVM is that when the runtime does its cleanup of the Heap it has to go through what is called a phase change.  It stops the threads running your application in order to mark and swap pointers to optimize your available memory.  Yong gen is faster as it is mainly releasing objects that are only temporary. Old gen, however, evaluates all the objects on the heap and when you run out of memory will it will kick of to free up much needed memory.

Why the Caution?  Old gen gets exponentially worse in pause time the more heap you use.  at 2-4 GB in total heap size you should be fine on modern runtimes like Java 6 (JDK 1.6+).  Once you go beyond that threashold you will see exponential increases in pause times.  I have run into some clients that have to restart servers - as in some rare cases where a heap is large GC pause times can take longer than a full restart.

There are some new tools out there that are pretty cool and can give you a leading edge on evaluating if GC is your pain.  JHiccup is one and it is free from the  [azulsystems](http://www.azulsystems.com/downloads/list)website.  At this time I think it is only for Linux though.  They also have a JVM that has a re-built GC algorithm that runs pauseless ... but if you are on a single server deployment with a non-critical app it may not be cost effective (that one is not free).

To sum up - if your runtime / JVM / CLR heap is less than 2 GB adding more memory will help.  Be sure to give yourself some overhead.  You never want to hit 100% Heap size / memory size if possible.  That is when the long pauses are the longest.  Give yourself an extra 20%+ memory over what you think you will need.  That way you have room for the GC algorithms to move objects around for optimization.  If you ever plan to go large ... there is one tool that fixes the circa 1990 JVM technology (Azul Systems Zing JVM), but it is not free.  They do offer an open source tool to diagnose GC issues.  The JVM (as I have tried it) also has a really cool thread level visibility tool that lets you report on any leaks, bugs, or locks in production without overhead (some trick with offloading data the JVM already deals with and time stamping).  That has saved tons of dev test time ... but again, not for small apps.

Stay below 4 GB.  Give extra headroom.  And if you want you can turn on these flags to monitor GC for Java / JVM:

```
java -verbose:gc myProgram
java -Xloggc:D:/log/myLogFile.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails myProgram
```

You may try some of the other collectors Hotspot uses.  There are more than one.

If you are on Linux go ahead and try the JHiccup tool as well.  It is free.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in trying the low-pause [Garbage-First collector](http://www.fasterj.com/articles/G1.shtml) instead of concurrent mark-sweep (although it's not necessarily more performant for all collections, it's supposed to have a better worst case). It's enabled by `-XX:+UseG1GC` and is supposed to be really awesomesauce, but you may want to give it a thorough evaluation before using it in production. It has probably improved since, but it seems to have been a bit buggy a year ago, as seen in [Experience with JDK 1.6.x G1 (“Garbage First”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986974/experience-with-jdk-1-6-x-g1-garbage-first)

Comment: I would point out that the Azul Zing jvm in many cases "is" more performant.  They do gC behind the scenes while the app is running.  Pretty cool stuff.  Again, it is not free, but for those wishing to do away with the need to tune a JVM this one can do it.  I think they call it their C4 collector (concurrent, continuous, compaction, collector?).  A recent benchmark by Mike McCandless tested it on Apache Lucene / Solr against CMS.  Great results in scalability: http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/07/lucene-index-in-ram-with-azuls-zing-jvm.html  I have been following this as it changes the game

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine for the garbage collection to run in parallel with your program, if you have plenty of cpu, which you do.

What you want, is to make absolutely certain that you will not run into a scenario where the garbage collection PAUSES your main program.

Have you tried simply not stating any flags except saying you want the server VM (for the Sun JVM), and then put your server under heavy load to see how it behaves?  Only then can you see, if you get any improvements from tinkering with options.

Answer (score 1):

This actually sounds like a throughput app and should probably use the throughput collector. I would balance the size of the new gen making it big enough to not GC too often and small enough to prevent long pauses. 20ms sounds like a long minor GC to me. I also suspect your survivor space is set too large and is just being wasted. If you don't have much surviving to old gen, you shouldn't have that much surviving your minor GCs.

In the end, you should use jvmstat and VisualGC to really get a feel for how your app is using memory.

Answer (score 1):

For high responsive server application, I think you want to see the major GC happens less frequently. Here is the list of parameters would help.

-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled 
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark 
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly 
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 
-XX:CMSWaitDuration=300000 
-XX:GCTimeRatio=40

Larger heap size may not help on low pause, as long as your app doesn't run out of memory.

Larger NewSize and MaxNewSize would help on throughput, may not help on low pause. If you choose to take this approach, you may consider give GC threads more execution time by setting -XX:GCTimeRatio lower. The point is to remember to take a holistic when tuning JVM.

Answer (score 0):

I think previous posters have missed something very obvious- the Perm Generation size is too low. If the system uses 200 to 400 MB as permanent generation- then it may be best to set Max Perm Gen to 400 MB. the PerGen size should also be set to the same value. You will then never run out of Permanent Generation Space.

Currently- it looks like the JVM has to spend a lot of time moving objects in and out of Permanent Generation. This can take time. JVM tries to allocate contiguous memory areas to Java Objects- this speeds memory access due to hardware level features. In order to do that, it is very helpful to have plenty of buffer in memory. If Permanent Generation is almost full, newly discovered permanent objects must be split or existing objects must be shuffled. This is what triggers a full GC, as well as causes long full GC pauses.

The question states that the Permanent Generation size has already been measured- if this has not been done, it should be measured using a tool. These tools process logs generated by the JVM with the verboseGC option turned on.

All the mark and sweep options listed above- may not be needed with this basic improvement.

People throw GC options as solutions without evaluating how mature they have proven to be in actual use.

Comment: I think you are confused about the Permanent Generation. It doesn't hold objects, it holds class definitions, class metadata, etc.