# High Frequency Trading in the JVM with Scala/Akka

Tags: performance, scala, jvm, akka, low-latency

Let's imagine an hypothetical HFT system in Java, requiring (very) low-latency, with lots of short-lived small objects somewhat due to immutability (Scala?), thousands of connections per second, and an obscene number of messages passing around in an event-driven architecture (akka and amqp?).

For the experts out there, what would (hypothetically) be the best tuning for JVM 7? What type of code would make it happy? Would Scala and Akka be ready for this kind of systems?

*Note:* There has been some similar questions, like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743106/tuning-jvm-gc-for-high-responsive-server-application), but I've yet to find one covering Scala (which has its own idiosyncratic footprint in the JVM).

Comment: Also the question arises if the JVM is the right choice? Maybe C++ would offer more predictable latency.

Comment: I've heard about Scala used to produce C code doing actual HFT, but I cannot recall any details. As the 1-3 sec mentioned in the linked question is too much for HFT, I don't think it is a good idea to write HFT software on JVM.

Comment: The question is way to general.

Comment: I just don't understand why people try low-latency in a garbage-collecting language.  Why isn't C more commonly used?

Comment: From my experience I can say that Scala is not good for high-performance with low latency, because of amount of magic going under the hood. Akka, also, is not the fastest thing, it is much slower than Disruptor.

Comment: You may have thousands of messages going in & out in a second, but you certainly won't have thousands of connections in an HFT system.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On my laptop the average latency of ping messages between Akka 2.3.7 actors is [~300ns](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/b288fffb32383addd9c86ddae18874d5ce8ffaf6/out0.txt#L314) and it is much less than the latency expected due to GC pauses on JVMs.

Code (incl. JVM options) & test results for Akka and other actors on Intel Core i7-2640M [here](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors).

P.S. You can find lots of principles and tips for low-latency computing on Dmitry Vyukov's [site](http://www.1024cores.net/) and in Martin Thompson's [blog](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/).

Comment: FYI, the improvement is now resolved and part of the JDK 7 newer releases.

Comment: Note: average latency is really just an inverse of the throughput.  You want to know the distribution of latencies based on when the messages should have been sent instead of when they were sent. i.e. you want to avoid co-ordinate omission.  http://www.azulsystems.com/sites/default/files/images/HowNotToMeasureLatency_LLSummit_NYC_12Nov2013.pdf

Comment: I removed reference to throughput test on typesafe blog to avoid misinterpretation that 1/latency = throughput.

Answer (score 38):

It is possible to achieve very good performance in Java.  However the question needs to be more specific to provide a credible answer.  Your main sources of latency will come from follow non-exhaustive list:

1. How much garbage you create and the work of the GC to collect and
   promote it.  Immutable designs in my experience do not fit well with
   low-latency.  GC tuning needs to be a big focus.
2. Warm up the JVM so that classes are loaded and the JIT has had time
   to do its work.
3. Design your algorithms to be O(1) or at least O(log2 n), and have
   performance tests that assert this.
4. Your design needs to be lock-free and follow the "[Single Writer
   Principle](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/single-writer-principle.html)".
5. A significant effort needs to be put into understanding the whole
   stack and showing mechanical sympathy in its use.
6. Design your algorithms and data structures to be cache friendly. 
   Cache misses these days are the biggest cost.  This is closely
   related to process affinity which if not set up correctly can result
   and significant cache pollution.  This will involve sympathy for the OS and even some JNI code in some cases.
7. Ensure you have sufficient cores so that any thread that needs to
   run has a core available without having to wait.

I recently blogged about a [case study](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/fun-with-my-channels-nirvana-and-azul.html) of such an exercise.

Answer (score 11):

You may find that use of a ring buffer for message passing will surpass what can be done with Akka. The main ring buffer implementation that people use on the JVM for financial applications is one called Disruptor which is carefully tuned for efficiency (power of two size), for the JVM (no GC, no locks) and for modern CPUs (no false sharing of cache lines).

Here is an intro presentation from a Scala point of view http://scala-phase.org/talks/jamie-allen-sdisruptor/index.html#1 and there are links on the last slide to the original LMAX stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There are HFT systems written in Java, lots of them, but I've never heard of a single one written in Scala. Why?

1. JVM languages, where garbage collectors is a common place, are not axactly a good choice for HFT. But Java is a garbage collected language. So, what is the trick? The trick is that people code HFT in Java as if they were using C, I mean: they trade some niceties Java offers by higher control of memory allocations. The trick is basically replacing the JCF (Java Collections Framework) by mundane arrays pre-allocated in memory, or some other creative solutions.
2. Scala is a functional programming language which promotes heavy use of functional programming techniques, most of them backed by the collections framework. The point is: if you are going to get rid of the collections framework (by item 1 above), you are basically not using the basic building blocks of FP built in Scala. If you are not doing that in the first place, what is the point of using Scala at all?
3. Akka does not look to be a good option because... well... it is written in Scala. So, but items (1) and (2), we can rule out Akka too.

The point is: Technology evolved since the question was proposed in 2012. My answer is now 10 years from the future. We have far more interesting options than C or C++, the only possible options in 2012.

OK... maybe not options (in plural)... but one option: Rust.

Rust is not a garbage collected language, it is a safe programming language, it productive, it offers a rich asynchronous library, and it is pretty fast.

The only "problem" with Rust is that people responsible for steering technology in big banks and financial institutions are, in general, averse to innovation, preferring things they already know since the beginning of their long careers. So, in a nutshell, it will take some time until we see HFT systems written in Rust.