# GC tuning while using Executors

Tags: java, garbage-collection, threadpool, executors

I have a server side application which uses `cachedThreadPool` (`Executors.newCachedThreadPool`. But I can see a drop in perfomance due to frequent GCs which might be cleaning the threads from `cachedpool`. Is there any way to tune GC for this scenario?

Comment: Are you sure the GC is removing the threads?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact case. Garbage collection logs will be helpful.

You can find out garbage collection tuning [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html).

Good explanations about your case can possibly found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743106/tuning-jvm-gc-for-high-responsive-server-application)